# Proving right isosceles triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

The right triangle XYZ with sides of lengths x and y, and hypotenuse of length z satisfies that z=√(2xy)  , and  the triangle XYZ is an  isosceles.
(This is my answer and I want to know your comments if my proof appropriate for the problem.)
[image]

Comment: +1 to your query, from (-1) back to (0).  On the one hand, your query violates the normal mathSE protocol of using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) rather than an image to display math.  On the other hand, the work that you showed is very good.  Your work contains a minor flaw that I will dissect in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

- Right $\triangle XYZ$
- Side lengths $x,y$ and hypotenuse $z$.
- $z = \sqrt{2xy}$

**To Prove:**

- $\triangle XYZ$ is an isosceles triangle.

---

Your analysis correctly showed that $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

But then, your analysis showed that if the triangle is
isosceles then $z = \sqrt{2xy}$.

This is the reverse of what you need to prove, which is that
if $z = \sqrt{2xy}$, then the triangle is isosceles.

The actual required completion of the problem is *similar*
to the work that you showed, trying to complete the problem.

$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = z = \sqrt{2xy} \implies x^2 + y^2 = 2xy \implies $

$(x - y)^2 = (x^2 + y^2 - 2xy) = 0 \implies (x - y) = 0 \implies $

$(x = y) \implies $ the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am current studying prove slowly by slowly and I guess i'm on the right track.

Comment: @AronLouiseC.Morales if this solution helped you pls click that tick mark below voting button to make it green